# What is what in the basement rough in

Tags: bathroom, basement, rough-in

When we bought this house we were told that the bathroom rough in was done.
What is the purpose of each pipe/hole? I'm assuming the larger one (blue cap) is for the toilet? Is this all we need to install 3 piece bathroom? Thank you.

[image]
[image]

Update:

The **blue** capped pipe is **3"**, **orange** capped pipe **2-1/2"** and orange **hole** in the floor **1-1/2"**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Need more info. It is difficult to tell what the overall layout is of the space with photos that just show individual pipes.

Comment: @Alaskaman, added more photos and measurement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blue capped pipe doesn’t look big enough. I think toilets need 3” poppies, unless there some kind of power flush.

Also, a floor mounted toilet comes with a set rough-in distance from the back wall (like 8”, 12”, etc.) and is centered on the toilet fixture. So, measure from the back wall AND from the side wall to see if it will fit. If a floor mount toilet won’t work, you may need to find a wall-hung toilet and use a drain line in the wall, if there is one.

Likewise, a tub or shower have limited distances for rough-in too.

Generally the sink drain can be routed around and tie into the shower or toilet drain. You just need adequate wall space to mount the cabinets, etc.

The vent could be a problem if they have not extended something up through the roof. Look in the ceiling joist space for a 1 1/2” to 2” pipe that has been capped.

Comment: Thank you, the thicker pipe is indeed 3". It's 10" away from the wall and 20" away from the furnace. I guess the floor mounted toilet works in this case.As for the vent, I don't see anything for now, but since I'm a newbie, I could be just missing it.

Comment: When measuring the toilet clearance don't forget to allow for wall finish thickness.