# Why would a rough in pipe be under the concrete?

Tags: concrete, basement, pipe, rough-in

I'm planning to install a three piece bathroom in the basement. We have 2.5" and 3.5" rough in pipes sticking out, while 2" pipe was fully in the concrete. I had to break the floor to see if it was actually a pipe cap.
We are not the first owners, so we don't know why contractors buried the 2" pipe like that. Is this a normal thing to do? Could it be cause previous owner wanted only 2 piece bathroom? As well do I need to make sure all pipes are connected and vented under the concrete or must it have been done correctly under the code anyways? We are in Canada.

[My related post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/140329/what-is-what-in-the-basement-rough-in)

Pics:

[image]
[image]

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If I had to guess I'd say that the builder expected the wall to pass over that point, and the vanity installed adjacent. You appear to have built your wall tight to the furnace, which isn't ideal for maintenance reasons. I'd bet that if you had set a wall 12" from the center of the 3" pipe it would line up with the 2" pipe.

As to why it's under the concrete... the plumber simply used too short a stub. Maybe he had a scrap laying around and wanted to use it up.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think all pipes are vented?